# Fetch email within variable then push event onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, email, variables

Need to push `qg("identify", {"email": "<email address of the user"});` when email form submit button is clicked. I need to push in the code from a third party solution where I can only use html/css/javascript.

**Here i insert the jquery ui popup form**

```
$.ajax({
  url: '//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js',
  dataType: 'script',
  cache: true,
  success: function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog();
  }
});
```

**Then i insert the jquery ui css in head**

```
$("<link/>", { rel: "stylesheet", type: "text/css", href: "//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"}).appendTo("head");
```

**Then I push the popup onto body**

```
$("body").append('<div id="dialog" title="BEVAKA PRODUKT"><div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user"><p class="validateTips">Här kan du skriva in din e-post och få ett mail när produkten finns i lager igen</p><form><fieldset><label for="email">E-postadress</label><input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"><input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px"></fieldset></form></div><button id="create-user">Bevaka</button></div>');
```

**Her I fetch email adress in var emailTest**

```
var emailTest = $("#email").val();
```

**Here I alert the emailTest variable on click**

```
$("#create-user").click(function(){
    alert(emailTest);
});
```

**This is what needs to be pushed when email form is submitted**

```
//qg("identify", {"email": "<email address of the user"});
```

**Protoype**

```
var email = $("#email").val();

$("#create-user").click(function(){
    qg("identify", {"email": "email"});
})
```

Comment: the email value wont stick in the variable

Comment: Try adding a few console logs in ajax success, click handlers. javascript / jquery is event based. So, you need to check / get the values when event happens rather than use the variable name.

Comment: @nightgaunt https://jsfiddle.net/hLcprteh/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hLcprteh/11/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned earlier, javascript / jquery is event based.

First of all,

```
$.ajax({
  url: '//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js',
  dataType: 'script',
  cache: true,
  success: function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog();
  }
});
```

You need to ensure that `#dialogue` exists before you call dialog on it. You have added the script to append the `#dialogue` div to body directly which will be triggered when the current script loads.

Similarly, when you add the code

```
var email = $("#email").val();
```

The variable will be assigned a value when current script loads. At that point of time, your email field is obviously empty.

You want to get the value of `#email` field when button is clicked. So move that code inside the click handler.

Comment: superhero is what you are